# FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter vs JQueryMvcFormUrlEncodedFormatter

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, formatter

I have created a default web api project with at least those 2 media formatters loaded. Both are for the same content-type:

```
FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
JQueryMvcFormUrlEncodedFormatter: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

When I do a simple http post form with `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` it works only with the `JQueryMvcFormUrlEncodedFormatter`, that means my sent complex object is not null at server side.

When I remove the formatter `JQueryMvcFormUrlEncodedFormatter` at application startup and do the simple http post form again I expect it to work again but it does not.

I get an exception that no appropriate formatter is loaded.

Thats not true -actually-

Why does it not work?

P.S.

I found that this is the difference:

```
– System.Net.Http.Formatting.FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter, for handling HTML form URL-encoded data
– System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.JQueryMvcFormUrlEncodedFormatter, for handling model-bound HTML form URL-encoded data
```

but I do not understand the difference!

I do not even use jquery to post my form:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="api/values"    enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter first name">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" placeholder="Enter last name">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: There's a precedence order, It always take the first Encoder in the list. Both Encoders, Jquery and the Form can handle the same type of request

Comment: I wrote that I deleted the jquery formatter and that the remaining formatter did not work. So what you say is either wrong or I did something wrong.

Comment: My mistake! Look the complete namespace of these two: Formatting and ModelBinding. Everything in the Formatting namespace is responsible for serializing and deserializing HTML message for the requested type. The ModelBinding, most precisely the JQueryMvcFormUrlEncodedFormatter is a MediaTypeFormatting for application/x-www-form-urlencoded request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter` binds **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** body to `FormDataCollection` type, and only that type.

`JQueryMvcFormUrlEncodedFormatter` however uses available ModelBinders to first parse the body to `FormDataCollection` and then use the first compatible ModelBinder to parse that into the final model. It's like mixing Model Binding approach and Media Type Formatting approach, which AFAIK is not explained anywhere in the WebAPI docs.

Both formatters are registered by default. This is what I inferred reading WebAPI source code.

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 out of box formatters

- `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`
- `XMLMediaTypeFormatter`
- `FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter`
- `JQueryMvcFormUrlEncodedFormatter`

  The first two media type formatters can serialize and deserialize CLR types to request/response and vice versa. But 3rd one neither serializes nor deserializes to/from any CLR type. 4th formatter can deserialize incoming raw data to CLR type.

  Hence in your case, you are experiencing with error after you remove `JQueryMvcFormUrlEncodedFormatter` since 3rd formatter could not able to deserialize incoming request data to CLR type.